# Difference between ListView and GridView

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview

I am new to flutter and till now I was using ListView to show items of my list. Today I encountered GridView and saw it doing the same. What is difference between the two? And which one to prefer?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between ListView and GridView is how it lays out its child. With ListView you are laying your children one by one either vertically or horizontally only. With GridView, its a combination of both. It lays its children horizontally first. When it exceeds the number specified in `crossAxisCount` which is the number of children in the cross axis, it proceeds to lay its next children to a new line.

Take a look at their differences shown in this picture:
[image]

Take a look at this article to deepen your understanding about ListViews and GridViews: https://medium.com/flutterfly-tech/flutter-listview-gridview-ce7177812b1d

Answer (score 1):

In ListView you are able to generate list of items aligned horizontally or vertically. Grid is almost same, but you can create table like layout with items aligned in columns and then in multiple rows. Take a look at official Flutter [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists). Or take a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutterfly-tech/flutter-listview-gridview-ce7177812b1d) article, which explains main differences between Grid and ListView.